# R chron %in% comparison only recognizes every second date

Tags: r, date, zoo, chron

I am using zoo and chron packages in R to read and transform data. At one point I need to select a part of a chron-indexed zoo object which corresponds to another chron object. Unfortunately, using %in% operator I only get part of the corresponding dates. Here is a MWE that reproduces the error:

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)
chron1 <- seq(chron("2013-01-01","00:00:00", format=c(dates="y-m-d",times="h:m:s")),
              chron("2013-01-01","03:10:00", format=c(dates="y-m-d",times="h:m:s")),by=1./1440.)
x1 <- runif(200)
z1 <- zoo(x1,chron1)
chron10 <- trunc(chron1, "00:10:00")
x10 <- aggregate(z1,chron10,FUN=sum)
which(index(x10) %in% chron1)
```

The (unexpected) output is:

```
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 10 12 14 16 18 19
```

Comment: It's not `chron1a`, it's `chron1`. Please edit the question.

Comment: This is a round off error issue, `index(x10)[1] - chron1[11]` outputs `[1] -0.006944444`. The following seems to solve it: `round(index(x10)) %in% round(chron1)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, post as answer?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Thanks, edited the question. 'round' unfortunately rounds to full days. Not sure it works for minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chron objects are floating point so there can be slight differences in what appears to be the same datetime depending on how they were calculated.  `format` them and compare those:

```
which(format(index(x10)) %in% format(chron1))
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

This also works as `trunc` uses an `eps` value to ensure that inputs slightly less than one minute are not truncated down a further minute. See `?trunc.times`

```
which(trunc(index(x10), "minutes") %in% trunc(chron1, "minutes"))
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Also see [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)